# Subgroup of $PGL(n(n-1)/2, \mathbb K)$ preserving the grassmannian $Gr(2, n)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, grassmannians, multilinear-algebra

How can we determine the subgroup of $PGL(\wedge^2 \bar{\mathbb Q}^n)$ which preserves the grassmamnnian $Gr(2, n)$ embedded as a projective variety in $\wedge^2(\bar{\mathbb Q}^n)$ via the Plucker embedding. For $n = 4$, this variety is a quadric and it is a known fact that the transformation group of $Gr(2,4)$ is the orthogonal group of the corresponding quadratic form (defined on $\bar{\mathbb Q}^6$ by a single Plucker relation).

One may approach this question  for $n = 5$ by considering the Plucker relations for $n = 5$ each of which yields a quadratic form and provided this is non-degenerate determine the corresponding orthogonal groups and finally take their intersection.

Is this a good approach. Is there an alternative method?

Comment: The automorphism group of $Gr(2,n)$ is $PGL(n)$. The question would be more appropriate on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is of course true.  Here we are actually seeking a subgroup of $PGL(\binom{n}{2}, \bar{\mathbb Q})$ that preserves the image of $Gr(2,n)$ in $\wedge^2 (\bar{\mathbb Q}^n)$. This is a non-trivial question (e.g. W. Nemitz Transformations Preserving the Grassmannian
William C. Nemitz,
Transactions of the American Mathematical Society Vol. 109, No. 3 (Dec., 1963), pp. 400-410)

Comment: It is the image of $\wedge^2:PGL(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}^n)\rightarrow PGL(\wedge^2\bar{\mathbb{Q}}^n)$.

Comment: Actually this is holds when n is not 4. For n = 4 Hodge-star operator is also preserving.